# Foreach result in textbox

Tags: c#, foreach

please view the code provided by Microsoft below:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Microsoft.Translator.Samples
{
class TranslateArraySample
{
    public static async Task Run(string authToken)
    {
        var from = "en";
        var to = "es";
        var translateArraySourceTexts = new []
        {
            "The answer lies in machine translation.",
            "the best machine translation technology cannot always provide translations tailored to a site or users like a human ",
            "Simply copy and paste a code snippet anywhere "
        };
        var uri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray";
        var body = "<TranslateArrayRequest>" +
                       "<AppId />" +
                       "<From>{0}</From>" +
                       "<Options>" +
                       " <Category xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<ContentType xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\">{1}</ContentType>" +
                           "<ReservedFlags xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<State xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<Uri xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<User xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                       "</Options>" +
                       "<Texts>" +
                           "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{2}</string>" +
                           "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{3}</string>" +
                           "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{4}</string>" +
                       "</Texts>" +
                       "<To>{5}</To>" +
                   "</TranslateArrayRequest>";
        string requestBody = string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", translateArraySourceTexts[0], translateArraySourceTexts[1], translateArraySourceTexts[2], to);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    Console.WriteLine("Request status is OK. Result of translate array method is:");
                    var doc = XDocument.Parse(responseBody);
                    var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2");
                    var sourceTextCounter = 0;
                    foreach (XElement xe in doc.Descendants(ns + "TranslateArrayResponse"))
                    {
                        foreach (var node in xe.Elements(ns + "TranslatedText"))
                        {
                            **Console.WriteLine("\n\nSource text: {0}\nTranslated Text: {1}", translateArraySourceTexts[sourceTextCounter], node.Value);**
                        }
                        sourceTextCounter++;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Request status code is: {0}.", response.StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Request error message: {0}.", responseBody);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Please look at the ** line, node.value is the result I want. According to the code, we will have 3 sentences translated from the string array above. However, I want it to display in a textbox. let say I have a textbox with ID = textbox.

I have tried using this :

```
foreach (var node in xe.Elements(ns + "TranslatedText"))
                    {
                       textbox.Text=node.value;
                    }
                    sourceTextCounter++;
```

However, the result only for the last sentence. 
Please share your thought how to do it!

Comment: You always set the whole text to the current string (`textbox.Text = node.Value;`). Instead you want to **append** the text: `textbox.AppendText(node.Value);`

Comment: all of you are correct. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  foreach (var node in xe.Elements(ns + "TranslatedText"))
  {
       textbox.Text += node.value + " ";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're always overwriting .Text you need to concatenate with something like:

```
textbox.Text += node.value + Environment.NewLine;
```

This would add your node.value and a newline character for each node found.

EDIT: Also want to state that Environment.NewLine is ignored if the Multiline property of the textbox is false.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this Environment.Newline();?

Comment: It's a property, not a method.  `Environment.NewLine`